# OpenCV solve returning constant value for arbitrary system?

Tags: c++, opencv, math, linear-algebra, equation

I initialize a 4x4 matrix to the identity matrix. Then I initialize a 4x1 vector B with random values. And I want OpenCV to solve the system Ax = B.

Since A is the identity, my expectation is that x = B.

However I am not getting that. First I code:

```
Mat A(Size(4,4), CV_64FC1);

// Identity matrix, by force
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
        if(i=j=) A.at<float>(i,j) = 1;
        else A.at<float>(i,j) = 0;
    }
}

Mat B(Size(4, 1), CV_64FC1);

B.at<float>(0, 0) = 1;
B.at<float>(1, 0) = 2;
B.at<float>(2, 0) = 3;
B.at<float>(3, 0) = 4;

Mat sol(Size(4, 1), CV_64FC1);

solve(A, B, sol, DECOMP_LU);
```

The output of the above is sol = <02313, 0, 0, 0>, rather than <1,2,3,4>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First size takes width as first parameter then height for some reason but Mat takes rows then cols which is a bit confusing to be honest x)

Second the 64fc1 is double i suppose not float the rest is working fine

```
Mat A(Size(4, 4), CV_64FC1);

    // Identity matrix, by force
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (i ==j) A.at<double>(i, j) = 1;
            else A.at<double>(i, j) = 0;
        }
    }
    Mat B(Size(1,4), CV_64FC1);

    B.at<double>(0, 0) = 1.0;
    B.at<double>( 1,0) = 2.0;
    B.at<double>(2, 0) = 3.0;
    B.at<double>(3, 0) = 4.0;

    Mat sol;

    solve(A, B, sol, DECOMP_LU);

    cout << sol << endl;
```